# Empty/Full Linked List

Tags: c++, list, pointers, linked-list

So for my **first question**. I'm working on a project and I need my constructor to create an empty linked list. Would this be correct?

```
// member variables
private:
   node* headptr;
   size_type howmany;

//constructor
SuperList::SuperList(){
    headptr = NULL; //does this create an empty list?
    howmany = 0; //counts how many nodes are in the list
}
```

**Second question.** I need to create a isEmpty() function and a isFull() function. For the isEmpty() function I just see if howmany == 0, right? But to check if list is FULL how would I do that? For normal arrays there is a CAPACITY, but there is no capacity given for linked lists.

```
    //these are the specifications I was given for the isFull function

    Effect: Determines if this list is full
    Precondition:  NONE
    Postcondition:  this object is unchanged
    Returns:  true if it is not possible to allocate any more memory, false otherwise

    bool SuperList::isFull() const
```

Comment: First question: Looks ok. Second question: a normal linked list can´t be full (except for full computer RAM, int overflowing etc.). What do you think you want to check?

Comment: Well, you edit is pretty clear. true if you can´t allocate. And you should probably check the int too.

Comment: Also in the postcondition it uses the term object instead of list. Is that a typo or does it actually mean object?

Comment: You could say the list is full when the number of elements equals `std::numeric_limits<size_type>::max()` ? I would not bother

Comment: Making an empty list is really easy: `void* list = nullptr`. It's when you want to be able to add stuff to it that it gets [more] complicated.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit That isn't an empty list, it's a null pointer.

Comment: @NeilKirk: And the functional difference is...?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit You can call `empty()` on an empty list.

Comment: @NeilKirk: It doesn't _have_ to be defined that way (i.e. as a member, and called `empty`) to meet the conditions of "being an empty list". I can write `bool is_an_empty_list(void* ptr) { return ptr == NULL; }` and, given the requirements stated, this is sufficient. There is a wider point here, though, which I feel you're not getting. :)

Answer (score 2):

**First question:**

- This is fine. Although, you probably want to add a node to keep track
  of the tail.

**Second question**

- `isEmpty()` can either be done by checking if `how_many` is zero or
  simply by checking if `headptr == NULL`.
- `isFull()` depends if you really want to set a limit to the length of the list. Generally speaking, lists can keep going only constrained by the amount of allocated memory available in the system. If your intent is to set a limit, then I would allow for the user to pass in a number through the constructor specifying their list size. From here you can simply use a counter to keep track...